# Moving a block in Trackmania Nations Forever's track editor

Tags: trackmania-forever

Is there any way to move a block in Trackmania Nations Forever's track editor? I would like to avoid having to delete it and creating it again at the desired location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TMNF it's impossible to move a block or a group of blocks but in TM² you can, Nadeo added a selection and copy/cut paste function (:

Answer (score 0):

Challenge Edit will do it (For reference, see necro ) It will even move blocks in validated track without borking the validation.

Comment: Could you elaborate? For anyone who have not used Challenge Edit before, this answer is not very helpful. A link to CE and an explanation of what necro means would improve your answer immensely.